# no visible @interface for 'Player' declares the selector 'walkRight'

Tags: ios, objective-c

// Player.m

```
#import "Player.h"
@implementation Player

+(id)player{

    Player *player = [Player spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor brownColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];

    player.name = @"player";

    player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.size];

    return player;

}



- (void)walkRight  {

    SKAction *incRight = [SKAction moveByX:10 y:0 duration:0];

    [self runAction:incRight];   

}


@end
```

// MyScene.h

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "Player.h"



@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    

   if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

       /* Setup your scene here */

       self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

       self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];



    SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 30)];

    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, -self.frame.size.height/2 + ground.frame.size.height/2);

    ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];

    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    [self addChild:ground];



    Player *player = [Player player];

    [self addChild:player];

}

return self;

}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

Player *player = (Player *)[self childNodeWithName:@"player"];

[player walkRight];



 }



-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

/* Called before each frame is rendered */

}



@end
```

I'm quite new to objective-c. Well I tried to build the above code and got the error "no visible @interface for 'Player' declares the selector 'walkRight'"
I really do not know why. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've declared the walkRight method in your Player.h file. This should go somewhere after your interface declaration in that file:

```
-(void)walkRight;
```

That allows other files that import Player.h to know that Player.m implements the walkRight method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your player method to return `instancetype` instead of `id`. This will make the warning go away. Also declare the `walkRight` method in the header (`.h`) file of your `Player` class.

```
+(instancetype)player{
    Player *player = [Player spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor brownColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];

    ....

    return player;
}
```

Read more about [`instancetype` here](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html).

Hope that helps!